# swift4: can't pass value to previous view controller from current popover

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift4

I'm using `swift4`, i present view controller modally as popover and want to pass data back to previous view controller when dismissing current popover, this is the first View controller :

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, PopoupDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var errorLable: UILabel!
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "pop") {
        let dest = segue.destination
           if let pop = dest.popoverPresentationController {
               dest.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.height - 20, height: 500)
               pop.delegate = self
           }
        }
    }

   func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
       return .none
   }

   func popupValueSelected(value: String) {
        print("value: ", value)
        self.errorLable.text = value
   }
}
```

and this the popover code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchPopoverViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var cityLable: UILabel!
   var delegate: PopoupDelegate?

   @IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       self.delegate?.popupValueSelected(value: "hiiiiii from the other side")
       self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

and this is the `PopoupDelegate`

```
import Foundation

protocol PopoupDelegate {
   func popupValueSelected(value: String)
}
```

when i click in the popover close button, the popover should dismiss and the `errorLable` in `SearchResultViewController` should change it's text to new passed text, but none happens, only the popover dismiss,
what should i do?

Comment: In this line self.delegate?.popupValueSelected(value: "hiiiiii from the other side") where is that delegate variable defined ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan sorry I forgot to copy it, i've edited the post, this is not the problem

Comment: check `self.delegate` in `SearchPopoverViewController` is it nil?

Answer (score 1):

You delegate function is wrong, function inside function in `SearchResultViewController`:

```
func popupValueSelected(value: String) {
   func popupValueSelected(value: String) {
       print("value: ", value)
       self.errorLable.text = value
   }
}
```

It should be:

```
func popupValueSelected(value: String) {
    print("value: ", value)
    self.errorLable.text = value
}
```

**After editing the question :**

You never assigned any instance to the delegate variable. `Try to change delegate variable name to popoUpDelegate.`

`pop.delegate` is for `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` not your delegate. This function should be like this :

```
if (segue.identifier == "pop") {
     if let dest = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController as? SearchPopoverViewController {
               dest.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.height - 20, height: 500)
               dest.popoUpDelegate = self
       }
   }
}
```

And your `SearchPopoverViewController` look like this :

```
class SearchPopoverViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var cityLable: UILabel!
   var popoUpDelegate: PopoupDelegate?

   @IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       self.popoUpDelegate?.popupValueSelected(value: "hiiiiii from the other side")
       self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define delegate to SearchResultViewController.

```
var PopoupDelegate : PopoupDelegate?
```

and before pop viewcontroller assign delegate to popoupDelegate

```
PopoupDelegate.delegate = self
```

and you have right function inside function. first make it correct.
Try this. Hope this will work. and let me know in case of any concern

Comment: i got this error Value of type 'PopoupDelegate?' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: ok sorry please try pop.PopoupDelegate= self before after your pop-viewcontrollers code.

Comment: i got the error: Value of type 'SearchPopoverViewController' has no member 'PopoupDelegate'

Answer (score 0):

When you are presenting `SearchPopoverViewController` from `SearchResultViewController` you need to set delegate.

**Using segue**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if (segue.identifier == "segueToPopOver") {

       let dest = segue.destination
       if let vc = dest.popoverPresentationController as? SearchPopoverViewController {

           //set other properties

           vc.delegate = self
       }
    }
}
```

**Using UINavigationController**

```
let vc = SearchPopoverViewController() // initialise view controller
vc.delegate = self
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Respond to delegate**

```
@IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
   self.delegate?.popupValueSelected(value: "hiiiiii from the other side")
   self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

In `SearchResultViewController` implement delegate method

```
func popupValueSelected(value: String) {
    print("value: ", value)
    self.errorLable.text = value
}
```

Comment: check self.delegate in SearchPopoverViewController is it `nil` or not?

Comment: sorry, i'm a beginner and i can't understand you, where to check it and i set print(self.delegate) it inviewDidLoad i got error Value of type 'SearchResultViewController' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: you need to add `print(self.delegate)` in `SearchPopoverViewController` and. check is it nil or not.

Comment: i got error Value of type 'SearchResultViewController' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: check in SearchPopoverViewController

Comment: how you are presenting `SearchPopoverViewController` ?

Comment: i perform a segue with identifier "pop" implement popover classes 
class SearchResultViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{}
and override it's functions as the above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172598/discussion-between-mahendra-gp-and-al-shimaa-adel).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how segues and protocols work for view controllers. Frankly, I would recommended reviewing the topic in [Apple's App Development with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11). This is written clearly with exercises to help you understand the basics of passing information between view controllers. I have been where you are, and while the suggestions and comments have been correct, you don't seem to have the foundation to understand what they are saying. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used popover dismiss delegate instead of protocol:
this code solved my problem:

in the `SearchResultViewController`:

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    if let searchPopoverViewController =
        popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController as? SearchPopoverViewController{
            self.passed_city_id = searchPopoverViewController.selected_city_id
    }
}
```

in the `SearchPopoverViewController`

```
@IBAction func searchButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    self.selected_city_id = 10

    popoverPresentationController?.delegate?.popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover?(popoverPresentationController!)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Unwind segue". pls refer

```
https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f
```